# Setting Cookie for Inappbrowser URL from IoniC

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cookies, inappbrowser

Am trying to set a cookie for inappbrowser url after its opened in IONIC application using tough-cookie.But it's not working.Can you please help me out.
Below is my code:

**Using Tough-Cookie**

```
var tough = require('tough-cookie');
var cookiejar = new tough.CookieJar();
cookiejar.setCookie("cookie-accepted=2",
 'http://currentdomain.example.com/path', function(err) 
   {console.log("err"+err);});
```

No error but cookie not set

**Using Cookie-Master**

```
cordova.cookieMaster.setCookieValue('https://www.url.fr', 'cookie-agreed', 
'2',
// function() {
//     console.log('A cookie has been set');
// },
// function(error) {
//     console.log('Error setting cookie: '+error);
// });
```

Getting error as cookieMaster of undefined.Tried cordova.plugins.cookieMaster also.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

While using cookie-master, you can access it in the window object as seen below.

```
(<any>window).cookieMaster.setCookieValue('domain.com', 'COOKIE_NAME', 'COOKIE_VALUE');
```

Cheers